# Unable to create IPA from Archive (Unity 3D)

Tags: ios, xcode7, ipa, unity-game-engine

The project is compiling without any errors in Xcode 7.3 but when I am trying to export the IPA for AdHoc it gets stuck while Compiling Bitcode. Please Help.

It gets stuck here:

[image: It gets stuck here...]

Comment: I'm suffering the same issue. It takes very long. But be patient. Sometimes it takes more than 1 hour at compiling bitcode. When I connected my macbook to 4G hotspot it dropped to 10 minutes once. Don't know what it has to do with internet but it helped me once.

Comment: Thanks, I almost lost my mind trying to figure what was wrong. It didn't take this long before though.

Comment: What I experienced is: bigger the project, longer it takes. Unity creates a pretty large project on export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait maybe till half an hour. Unity code takes time creating binary due to its size.